# python 2d matrix manipulation need help without numpy

Tags: python

i want to "pop" a spot in a 2D array in python 
the code:

```
w, h = 8, 8;
Matrix = [["#" for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)] 


for w in Matrix:
    for h in w:       
     print("#",end = " ")
    print()




numA = int(input())
numB = int(input()) 

Matrix.pop(numA - 1)(numB - 1) #the part i need help with**
Matrix[numA - 1][numB - 1] = J = 1

for w in Matrix:
    for h in w:       
     print("@",end = " ")
    print()
```

it doesnt work.
what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you elaborate on why you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1):

`pop` only works on a list - ie. in your case on a row. So:

```
Matrix[numA - 1].pop(numB - 1)
```

will remove `numB`th element from `numA`th row.